# Managing pdf´s in Linux

Tags: editor

I've using mac for more than 10 years. And now, suddenly, I'm a Linux user.
So far I've manage my self to do almost everything I used to do regularly in my mac, in great part thanks to the chrome platform and G Suite.

But there are a few simple things related to pdf management that I have not being able to accomplish, yet.

I get to deal with a lot of documents in my work, most of them pdf files, and every once in a while, I get one of this files that needs to be rotated, splited and annotated. In my mac not that only it was very very easy, but I do it with a single app!: Preview.

Can you please help me to find a replacement solution to accomplish all this?. It will be great if it is a single app, and I'm willing to pay for it. It can be a Linux (debian or flatpack, Iḿ using Elementary OS) or it can be a web app.

1. Rotate pdf easily without loosing quality in a single step. The quality part is very important because it needs to be equally readable.
2. Split pdf in parts easily in a single step.
3. Annotate pdfs with geometric shapes, text and arrows...

So far i found two different apps for doing steps 2 and 3:

PDF Tricks https://github.com/muriloventuroso/pd...
LibreOffice Draw https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/...

But I don't like very much nether of them, for the 1 part (rotate easily) I'm clueless. Please help

Thank you very much for reading into this point, this community is the best part of being a #linuxuser #elementaryOS[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/ILNaKoThYPY)

Answer (score 1):

If it is only about rotation of the pdf, it can be easily done by Evince, the default Document viewer for Elementary Os, I do not know about the default version, but I did upgrade it with the flatpak version and rotation is easy done with not notable quality loss, at least i do not notice any.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Master PDF Editor for Linux](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/)? It seems to encompass everything you required, and more. Here's s short list of capabilities (from their website):

```
Modify text and objects
Annotate PDF documents
Create and fill in PDF forms 
Optical character recognition in PDF
Operations on PDF pages
PDF Bookmarks
Digital signatures 
Create PDF documents
```

Use [this link to download the .deb file](https://code-industry.net/get-master-pdf-editor-for-ubuntu/?download). Then install [Eddy](https://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.eddy/) and use it to open the .deb file and install Master PDF Editor.

[image]

The free version will add watermarks on saved documents, and restricts access to several features. The [full version](https://code-industry.net/purchase-masterpdfeditor/) is available from around $70.

EDIT: If you want to, you can use [PDF Tricks' GitHub page](https://github.com/muriloventuroso/pdftricks/issues) to get in touch with the developer, and describe the features you'd like to see implemented. Use the `New Issue` button to create a new ticket to request a new feature, and give as many details as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much!, so nice from you. Happy Holidays ☃️

Comment: Happy Holidays to you too!